# Pandas operation, putting multiple results into a df column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is a quant work. I used my previous work to filter out some desired stocks(candidates) with technical analysis based on moving average, MACD, KDJ, and etc. And now I wanna check my candidates' fundamental values, in this case, ROE. here is my code:

```
    root_path = '.\\__fundamentals__'

    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("C:\\candidates.csv", encoding='GBK'))  # 14 candidates this time
    for code in list(df['code']):
        i = str(code).zfill(6)

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
            for csv in files:
                if csv.startswith('{}.csv'.format(i)):
                    csv_path = os.path.join(root, csv)  # based on candidates looking for dupont value

                    df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("{}".format(csv_path), encoding='GBK'))
                    df2['ROE'] = df2['净资产收益率'].str.strip("%").astype(float)/100
                    ROE = [df2['ROE'].mean().round(decimals=3)]
                    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ROE_Mean': ROE})
                    print(df3)
```

Here is the DOM

```
C:\Users\Mike_Leigh\.conda\envs\LEIGH\python.exe "P:/LEIGH PYTHON/Codes/Quant/analyze_stock.py"
   ROE_Mean
0    -0.218
   ROE_Mean
0     0.121
   ROE_Mean
0     0.043
   ROE_Mean
0     0.197
   ROE_Mean
0     0.095
   ROE_Mean
0     0.085
...
   ROE_Mean
0     0.178

Process finished with exit code 0
```

my desired output would be like this:

```
   ROE_Mean
0    -0.218
1     0.121
2     0.043
3     0.197
4     0.095
5     0.085
...
14     0.178
```

Would you please give me a hint on this? Thanks alot, much appreciated!

Comment: I would probably just append `ROE_Mean` to a list and turn it into a dataframe outside the loop

Answer (score 2):

acually I wasn't that bad solving the issue.
first, make a list outside the loop, I mean the very outside the loop, in this case, before `df`

```
roe_avg = []
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("C:\\candidates.csv", encoding='GBK'))
....
    df2['ROE'] = df2['净资产收益率'].str.strip("%").astype(float) / 100
    ROE_avg = df2['ROE'].mean().round(decimals=3)
    roe_avg.append(ROE_avg)
df['ROE_avg'] = roe_avg
print(df)
```

DOM

```
        name    code  ROE_avg
1   仙鹤股份  603733    0.121
3   泸州老窖     568    0.197
4   兴蓉环境     598    0.095
...
15  濮阳惠成  300481    0.148
16  中科创达  300496    0.101
17  森霸传感  300701    0.178

Process finished with exit code 0
```

thanks to @filippo